# How to redirect anonymous users to login page using Rules module?

Tags: rules, users

I'm using rules module with drupal 7 in order to redirect anonymous users to the login page, so I created a rule with react on event "Drupal is initializing", condition "User has role" with anonymous user and "Not site login url", then added an action "Page redirect" to site login url. When I tried to test the rule; drupal kept redirecting to the login page over over and over until apache server stopped working. Any recommendations.

Comment: can anonymous user explore site content? for what reason need to redirect login page?

Comment: anonymous users are not allowed to explore any site content and not allowed to register except with an invitation. Users have to login to use the site.

Comment: I don't understand this part "rule drupal kept redirecting to the login page without showing it."  Could you explain what you mean?  Otherwise I'm not sure I understand which part isn't working.

Comment: Well when I go to the homepage or any other page but not login page the rule works fine; its redirecting the user to the login page, however the browser keeps redirecting to login page over and over until apache stops working.

Comment: if anonymous users are not allowed to explore any site content, then remove permission to view content

Comment: @monymirza I didn't get what you mean by "remove permission to view content" I just want anonymous users to be redirected to login page every time they access the website

Comment: It sounds like the test in the rule for not being on the login page already is not working. Disable the rule and make a copy of it that instead of redirecting does some other action such as displaying a message, and see if the condition is working correctly.

Comment: Try to add "site:current-user:uid == 0" condition instead of checking a role.

Comment: @Leksat, thanks for you comment. Your solution will not change anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I solved it as follow:

- **Events:** Drupal is initializing
- **Conditions:**

  1. *User has role(s)* - `Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: anonymous user`
  2. *NOT Text comparison* - `Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user/login`
- **Actions:** *Page redirect* - `Parameter: URL: user/login`

---

Export rule as follow:

```
{ "rules_login" : {
    "LABEL" : "login",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "login" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1" } }
        }
      },
      { "NOT text_matches" : { "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ], "match" : "user\/login" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "user\/login" } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @TopTomato this is for drupal 7

Comment: i made an error and it is working.

Comment: @TopTomato Awesome! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `/admin/people/permissions` uncheck View published content for anonymous users

[image]

now go to `/admin/config/system/site-information` add 'user' in (access denied) page field

[image]

Comment: good work around, but I still need to show access denied page because not all users have the same permissions. I appreciate your help.

Comment: then remove 'user' from (access denied) page field at 2nd step

Comment: if I remove it; anonymous users can only see access denied without redirecting to the login page. I'm sure that there's a way I can do it in rules module

Comment: yes. further can be done by rules module. you can also do it via trigger core module.

Comment: I will look into trigger module, thanks for your help

Comment: If someone has access denied does not mean they are not logged in.[See This Answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224407/20563)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can pull this off with rules, but it would be easy to do in your theme's template.php file as well.

Something like this should work:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 0 && arg(0) != 'user' && arg(1) != 'login'){
  drupal_goto('user/login');
}
```

Or, if access to the user/registration & user/password pages is still wanted:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == 0 && arg(0) != 'user'){
  drupal_goto('user/login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chance I already found this solution before I posted my question. I want to use rules module or at least understand why its not working with "Drupal is initializing"

Comment: @Chance, I'm curious. Where would this live within the .theme file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the event in question. Instead of `Drupal is initializing`, try `Content is viewed`.

Comment: I tried it before I post this question and it worked fine with me except with view pages, registration page, basically any page that is not node.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a post from two years ago.  However, the solution for redirecting an anonymous user to the user login page with rules is as follows:

- event: System log entry is created
- condition: User has role(s): anonymous
- action: page redirect value: user

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: have you tried your solution before you post it here?