# How to add login form to the Access Denied page?

Tags: forms, users

I'm trying to add a login form to the access denied page, and wonder if this is possible via the UI.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Place Login Block on 404 page callback & Use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/blocks404 or use this module if using Drupal 7 https://www.drupal.org/project/navigation404

Comment: That is for the "page not found" error, not the "access denied" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution here is the the [LoginToboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan). It provides a number of different enhancements to login functionality.

> The logintoboggan module offers several modifications of the drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the following features
>   and usability improvements:
>
> 1. allow users to login using either their username or their e-mail address.
> 2. allow users to login immediately.
> 3. provide a login form on access denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> 4. the module provides two login block options: one uses javascript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log
>      in". the other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the
>      user to their original page upon login.
> 5. customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> 6. optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> 7. optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> 8. optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> 9. optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
> 10. optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the caveats section of install.txt
>       for important information on configuring this feature!).
> 11. integrates with rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see
>       http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

The settings configuration form has an option called *Present login form on access denied (403)* that toggles this exact functionality on/off.

Comment: LoginToboggan module worked like a charm had to include the 403 page but it was super, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

## Option 1: Use the CustomError module

The [CustomError](https://www.drupal.org/project/customerror) module allows the site admin to create custom error pages for HTTP status codes 403 (access denied) and 404 (not found), without the need to create nodes for each of them. Some more details about its features (from its project page):

> - Configurable page title and descriptions.
> - There are no author and date/time headers as with normal nodes.
> - Any HTML formatted text can be be put in the page body.
> - The error pages are themable.
> - Users who are not logged in and try to access an area that requires login will be redirected to the page they were trying to access after they login.
> - Allows custom redirects for 404s.

You should be interested in the part about "*Users who are not logged in and try to access an area that requires login will be redirected to the page they were trying to access after they login.*".

## Option 2: Redirect to user/login using the Rules module

*"Adding settings for the 'access denied page' and displaying the 'User login' block on that page"* is indeed a solution that should work. However, you could take this a little step further, and enhance the user experience AbitMORE. By using a variation of the approach described in the answer to the question about "[How to redirect anonymous users to login page using Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50300/how-to-redirect-anonymous-users-to-login-page-using-rules-module)".

To do so, assume the path of the "Default 403" page is set to "no_access" (via `/admin/config/system/site-information`, near the bottom of that admin page). Then create a rule using the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module, with as **Event** something like "After visiting node 'no_access'". So that the entire rule would look something like so:

- **Events:** After visiting node 'no_access'
- **Conditions:**

  1. *User has role(s)* - `Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: anonymous user`
  2. *NOT Text comparison* - `Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:url], Matching text: user/login`
- **Actions:** *Page redirect* - `Parameter: URL: user/login`

Should you want to do so, you could even add another **Action** to also display some (informational) message in the Drupal message area, with something like "You tried to visit a page for which login is required ...".

True, it might require you to enable an extra contributed module ([Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules)). But, as indicated by its growing popularity also, that module is probably already enabled in mostly any site (similar to the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module), because there are dozens of use-cases for this module. Just 1 variation of this question: how about enhancing the user experience for "Page not found" in a similar way?

## Option 3: Show User login block on dedicated page

Another variation, as an alternative to the Rules "Action" (to redirect to `user/login`), is to create some designated node, say with a path like "my_login_page_with_login_block". And then combine this with configuring the "User login" block (via `admin/structure/block`) like so:

- Display that block in whatever theme region of your choice.
- Use the "`configure`" link to the right of that User login bloc, to set the "*Visibility settings*" for "*Pages*". I.e. change the option for "*Show block on specific pages*" to "*Only the listed pages*", and specify the path (`my_login_page_with_login_block`) within the text box below it. If for some reason you don't want to use a path, then just specify node/nid (nid = id of the node) as the path instead.

Comment: Hi Pierre, this is a big help, I will try this and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ... Hopefully you won't forget to some day "get back" with your feedback about it (after you tried it). Too bad there is not such a thing as "remind me later" (to come back to it), eg implemented using something like 'Rules Scheduler' and/or "Flag' (as we'd do in Drupal, right?) ... Note to myself: add such feature in the "ArrayShift" distribution ...

Comment: Well it has extended my knowledge but not answered the question yet, its a big help but still not reached the promised land.

Comment: LoginToboggan module worked like a charm

Comment: Got be honest guys we went with LoginToboggan module.

Comment: No problem of course, let's consider it as Drupal's flexibility and options to pick what's right for everyone individually!

Answer (score 5):

You can add settings for  'Default 403 (access denied) page' in the site configuration (admin/config/system/site-information). And then display 'User login' block (admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure) on this page.

Answer (score 3):

Without the [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module one can configure the User login block to be visible on designated pages and restricted to anonymous users.  In the block Visibility settings for the User login block:

1. In the "pages" tab, set "Show block on specific pages" to "Only the listed pages" and enter the pages.
2. In the "Roles" tab, check "anonymous user" for the Show block for specific roles setting.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could set the Default 403 (access denied) page under Site information to user/login at /admin/config/system/site-information.

Never tried it but it's just an idea?

Comment: Bad idea. Logged in users who get access denied end up in endless redirect loop that causes browser crash.